# How to print the child process with their name and pid once under the last child fork()

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I am learning how to generate process in Linux using C++ `fork()` method. When i tried to print out their pid with ChildA,B,C i have created. It print out twice. If i only want them print once, how can i change the code.

I tried to put an count under the print out command. When it print out once it should stop and not more printing again.

```
child_C=fork();
if(Child_C==0){
  //do some function here;
}else{
  child_B=fork();
  if(Child_B==0){
    //do some function here;
    }else{
     child_A=fork();
     if(x==0){
        cout<<"i am child A" << child_A << "\n";
        cout<<"i am child B" << child_B << "\n";
        cout<<"i am child C" << child_C << "\n";
        x++;
     }
     if(Child_A==0){
        //do some function here;
     }else{
         //do some function here;
     }
  }
}
```

i expect the output:

```
i am child A 123
i am child B 234
i am child C 345
```

but it prints out:

```
i am child A 123
i am child B 234
i am child C 345
i am child A 0
i am child B 234
i am child C 345
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 child_A=fork();
 if(x==0){
    cout<<"i am child A" << child_A << "\n";
    cout<<"i am child B" << child_B << "\n";
    cout<<"i am child C" << child_C << "\n";
    x++;
 }
```

Either `x` is 0 or it's not. If `x` is zero, then neither of the processes returning from the `fork` call will produce output. If `x` is not zero, then both processes will produce output. So your expected output seems impossible. How can each of these output lines run once?

Presumably, `x` was zero. So both processes produced output. The differt "child A" values show that one of these came from the parent and one from the child.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to where your last fork is in relation to the couts. If you'll notice, the PID for child A is different each time it is printed, while the other two are the same. The PID will be 0 if it's the child, while the PID will be something else if it's the parent. Since the child A prints two different things, it's happening in both the child and the parent.